# crystal report showing sub total after each date

Tags: crystal-reports

i am not able take sub total depend upon date..i want to show my report like this:i mean i want to show subtotal after each date
my report is coming like this:

```
LocName   Date          un1     un2      carcount
-------------------------------
Address  2013-01-10      compl  compl      10
                         compl  compl       12
                                          --------
                                     SubTotal  20
         2013-01-15      comple   comple      5        
                         comple   compl       10
                                           -------   
                                           SubTotal  15
```

---

```
                                      Grand Total 35
             i am not able to give sub total after each date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is a running total rather than a standard summary field.

Go to the field explorer and right click on Running Totals:

[image: Step 1]

In the next screen add `carcount` to the fields to summarise, set the summary type to sum and set `Evaluate` to 'For each record'

Now you can add the new running total to the report and it should calculate correctly

**Edit:**

To display field types right click on 'Database Fields' in the field explorer:

[image: Types]

Comment: in the summary type i am not getting Sum..so what to do?

Comment: Is the `carcount` field a number? You can check this in Field Explorer by right clicking and selecting `show field type`.

Comment: carcount data type System.Int64

Comment: Crystal Reports has problems with `Int64`, it tends to convert it to a string. You may need to cast it to `System.Int32` to get it working correctly. If you are dealing with numbers over the 32 bit limit then you might have to look at a different solution!

Comment: sir..i am dealing with numbers..so if i given int 32..it should work? or i have to go for any other solution??

Comment: Yes Int32 should work normally, in Crystal Reports it should show as type `Number` rather than `System.Int64` once it's working.

Comment: i try to check carcount type..but i havnt find any show field type field?

Comment: I've added a shot to show how to do this, if you're using Crystal Reports within `Visual Studio` you'll need to set it a different way.

Comment: In that case it may still display the different type, you'd need to either convert the field in the dataset to a 32 bit integer or translate to a 32 bit integer in code on the fly.